# Looking for a comprehensive list of allergies

Tags: side-effects, allergy, allergen

I need to put together a list of allergies for a software project I am working on.
Can someone direct me to a site or book that contains a navigational or indexed list of allergies?

What I need is Something like :

- Drug allergies - Penicillin
- Natural allergies - Fish, Pollen
- Chemical Allergies - Latex
- Etc...

I tried Google, but I could only find sites that mention "[10 common allergy triggers](https://www.webmd.com/allergies/ss/slideshow-common-allergy-triggers)", "top 15 allergies", etc..

Answer (score 4):

You may find [SNOMED CT](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/healthit/snomedct/index.html) useful. As you can see from this screenshot from the [UMLS Metathesaurus](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/knowledge_sources/metathesaurus/index.html), SNOMED CT contains many allergies organized into a useful [ontological hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology#Types_of_ontologies):

[image: Image showing the hierarchy of allergy to peanut]

Here "allergy to peanut" is an "allergy to pulse vegetable", which in turn is an "allergy to food".

By starting at "allergy to substance" you can get many thousands of allergies.

Note that you need a [license to use SNOMED CT](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/healthit/snomedct/snomed_licensing.html) and in South Africa, you'll need an [affiliate license](https://ihtsdo.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/4000039015-how-do-i-obtain-a-snomed-ct-affiliate-license-).

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. This wont work for me. I am working on a personal non commercial project. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Have you actually tried contacting them? If it's non-commercial, I bet they will give you a license for free. I got my academic license through the US NLM in about 5 minutes.